# Deploy Outlook Desktop Add-in

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins, yeoman-generator

I need to deploy an add-in created in yeoman on the outlook desktop.
How could I do it without using the local host?
Could it be done with an installer?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You need to deploy the add-in (web app) on any web server and share the manifest file for sideloading (or just publish the add-in to the store).`